# Error:(116) Error: Expected resource of type id [ResourceType]

Tags: java, android

When i debugged my app there aren't errors, but when I generate signed app there is this error:

```
   /Users/dariobrun/Documents/AndroidStudioProjects/PGNChessEditor/app/src/main/java/it/dario/brun/pgnchesseditor/app/PannelloScacchiera.java:116: Error: Expected resource of type id [ResourceType]
            black.setId(1);
                        ~

       Explanation for issues of type "ResourceType":
       Ensures that resource id's passed to APIs are of the right type; for
       example, calling Resources.getColor(R.string.name) is wrong.

    1 errors, 0 warnings

     FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
    > Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.

      To proceed, either fix the issues identified by lint, or modify your build script as follows:
      ...
      android {
          lintOptions {
              checkReleaseBuilds false
              // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
              // but continue the build even when errors are found:
              abortOnError false
          }
      }
      ...

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD FAILED in 3s

    25 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 22 up-to-date
```

This is java code that generated error:

```
  black=new RadioButton(context);
    black.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.pannello_size));
    black.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.moveblack));
    black.setId(1);
```

But even it says "build failed" the signed apk was generated and it works fine.
So, what's happened? Should I get worried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.

Read about [**`lint`**](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html)

The Android plugin for Gradle allows you to configure certain lint options, such as which checks to run or ignore, using the **`lintOptions {}`** block in your module-level `build.gradle` file.

```
 lintOptions 
   {
       abortOnError false
       checkReleaseBuilds false
   }
```

After that **`CLEAN-REBUILD-RUN`** .